# PrestaShop 1.7 with PHP Xdebug getting exception and exclude files in script not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, prestashop, xdebug, prestashop-1.7

Using PrestaShop 1.7 to develop my application and using Xdebug to debug my code. The Xdebug doc link is https://xdebug.org/docs/.

But it will get exception every time which says that

> "Integrity check failed."

debug script is

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,

    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
}
```

The xdebug console showing response

```
connection 7: read ECONNRESET
{ XDebugError: command is not available
    at new Response (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:56:19)
    at new BreakpointSetResponse (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:207:9)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:599:20)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:4:58) code: 5, name: 'XDebugError' }
{ XDebugError: command is not available
    at new Response (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:56:19)
    at new BreakpointSetResponse (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:207:9)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:599:20)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:4:58) code: 5, name: 'XDebugError' }
```

This exception is from `/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Crypto.php`

I am trying to exclude folders and files like `vendor`,`var`,`classes/Tools.php`

How can I resolve this issue? Is there any other debugging tool support PrestaShop?

Comment: Ask the support of the vendor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue by ignoring vendor folder.I am not sure this is the right way.
Changed debug script is

```
 {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**",
                "**/var/**",
                "**/src/**",
                "**/classes/Tools.php",
                "**/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution
I solved issue by ignoring the files and folders that presented errors.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "ignore": [
            "**/vendor/**",//folder
            "**/src/**",//folder
            "**/var/**",//folder
            "**/classes/module/**",//folder
            "**/classes/Tab**",//file
            "**/classes/Media**",//file
            "**/classes/helper/**"//folder
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
```